# Pentaho Data Integration Define Dependencies

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am using Pentaho Data Integration to create a job where several sql tables are created.
Here is the job:
[image]

I would like to create TABLE_D when both TABLE_C and TABLE_B are created, however it seems like first the tables in the first branch are created and then TABLE_D is created, and the job then continues to create TABLE_B.

How can I enforce the creation of TABLE_B AND TABLE_C before TABLE_D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you defined it, TABLE_D is called twice, once after successfully calling TABLE_C, and another when TABLE_B succeeds.

To do what you want you have two options:

1. Just put them on a single chain: TABLE_A->TABLE_B->TABLE_C->TABLE_D. Sure, it adds another constraint in that TABLE_C is only created after TABLE_B, but does what you need it to.
2. Put the first 3 statements in a sub job. And the parent job calls TABLE_B after the successul end of the sub-job, which will only happen once.